# Get map key name and values stored on array from firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get the values from a map and store it in an array from firestore using react native. This is an example of how I would like the array to look, after the map gets pulled.

```
const [food, setFood] = useState([
    {Food: 'Cheese', Calories: 20, Quantity: 1, key: '1'},
    {Food: 'Lettuce', Calories: 10, Quantity: 1, key: '2'},

]);
```

Here is the stored data in firestore:
[image: firestore data]

For getting the data and other fields from firestore I'm using this function:

```
const getFoodData = async () =>{

    const docRef = doc(db, "foods", uid);
    const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
    
    if (docSnap.exists()) {
      console.log("Document data:", docSnap.data());
    } else {
      console.log("No such document!");
    }
        setFood(docSnap.get("Food.Cheese.Calories"))
        console.log(food)
}
```

I'm able to get the value from an individual field by doing the above, but I need to have it stored in an array, like the first example. how would I be able to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `Object.keys()` and then use a map as shown below:

```
const foodMap = docSnap.data().Food

const result = Object.keys(foodMap).map(key => ({ food: key, ...foodMap[key] }))
```

Comment: so does this mean that result is an array, which has the following structure:

    {Food: 'Cheese', Calories: 20, Quantity: 1, key: '1'},
    {Food: 'Lettuce', Calories: 10, Quantity: 1, key: '2'}

Comment: @AngelAngelov Food is a map in your document. `Object.keys()` will be an array of all keys in Food map. Then you map an array from it. Have you tried logging result as in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71631728/6672427), Dharmaraj.

Adding code snippet so you can see it in action -

```js
// Food is the result of doc.data().food
const food = {
  Cheese: { Calories: 20, Quantity: 1, key: '1'},
  Lettuce: { Calories: 10, Quantity: 1, key: '2'},
};

console.log('Firestore Data: ', food)

const result = Object.keys(food).map(key => ({ food: key, ...food[key]}))

console.log('Flattened result: ', result)
```